# How to handle specific Exceptions of a package (not Built-in Exceptions)

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

For example, in `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs()`, (which is ARPACK) it may raise an exception `ArpackNoConvergence` if it doesn't converge. 
(See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs)

In my code right now, I do

```
try:
    # do some eigs() that doens't converge
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
converged = e.eigenvalues
```

This works, but of course `Exception` can be anything. If it's not the `ArpackNoConvergence` as expected, it may not contain the `eigenvalues` attribute.

Question is what can I do to catch the specific Exception? If I modify the code to

```
try:
    # do some eigs() that doens't converge
except ArpackNoConvergence as e:
    print(e)
converged = e.eigenvalues
```

This raises a syntax error since `NameError: global name 'ArpackNoConvergence' is not defined`.

So how do I do this?

Comment: `from scipy.sparse.linalg import ArpackNoConvergence`

Comment: Thanks! This works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the import statement you should have an entry like this

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack import eigs, ArpackNoConvergence
```

So the except block look like this

```
except ArpackNoConvergence as err:
    k = len(err.eigenvalues)
    if k <= 0:
        raise AssertionError("Spurious no-eigenvalues-found case")
    print err.eigenvalues, err.eigenvectors
```

Comment: Thanks! Yep this makes so much sense:)